# Nodejs access netserver write from outside?

Tags: node.js

Looking at the following example:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('server connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('server disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

I want to have a way to access c.write from outside of the `createServer()` function

Basically what i want to do is this:

```
app.get('/msg/:theMsg', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

server.c.write(req.params.theMsg, socketName); // i got socketName stored in an array

});
```

Comment: What is there to write to if there is no established connection?

Comment: The logic of my server requires me to be able to check if connection X is active and then send c.write to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this, however you will have to do more checks to see if the socket is still alive or not, etc.

```
var net = require('net');
var sockets = {};
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
    var name = generate_name_from_con(c);
    console.log('server connected');
    sockets[name] = c;
    c.on('end', function() {
        delete sockets[n];
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });
    c.write('hello\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound');
});

app.get('/msg/:theMsg', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if(socketName in sockets) sockets[socketName].write(req.params.theMsg);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `c` object as parameter to another function:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
   console.log('server connected');
   c.on('end', function() {
      console.log('server disconnected');
   });
   writestuff(c);
   c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
   console.log('server bound');
});
function writestuff(c) {
   c.write('eueueueue');
}
```

Comment: How would i do that the other way around? See my app.get example above, that would not contain the c parameter

Comment: `app` comes from where? is related to `server` somehow?

Comment: app is triggered when the server receives a get request its outside of the scope of the net server

Comment: Ahh you are creating a web server AND an tcp server